# How Can I Appropriately Live Life Accordingly to God's Will?

Tags: will-of-god

I have been struggling for the past five years. My civil rights were violated about three to four times and all being investigated by the Federal Bureau of Investigation. I am currently unemployed. I have had no luck in trying to get my portfolio of fantasy novels published either. It is still a professional hobby of mine where I have not earned any money. I am looking for an agent and publisher to no avail. Is this all part of God's will for my life? How do I know if I am living a life according to God's will?

Comment: Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

Comment: _"How do I know if I am living a life according to God's will?"_ The Apostle Paul discusses this in great detail in [Romans 12-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+12&version=NIV): 12:2 being the key verse, and the next 3 chapters discussing what it looks like. If I get time in the next couple of days (and the question remains open) I might try to convert some of what he says into an answer to your final question (or others can give it a go!)

Answer (score 0):

God's will for a specific human life has less to do with what the circumstances of the life are and more to do with how that life responds to the circumstances.  Insofar as God orchestrates or allows the particular circumstances of a life He does so for two main reasons:

In order to give birth to faith,

> The God who made the world and everything in it, being Lord of heaven and earth, does not live in temples made by man, nor is he served by human hands, as though he needed anything, since he himself gives to all mankind life and breath and everything.  And he made from one man every nation of mankind to live on all the face of the earth, **having determined allotted periods and the boundaries of their dwelling place**,  **that they should seek God, and perhaps feel their way toward him and find him**. Yet he is actually not far from each one of us, - Acts 17:24-27

or to refine faith,

> Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ! According to his great mercy, he has caused us to be born again to a living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead,  to an inheritance that is imperishable, undefiled, and unfading, kept in heaven for you,  who **by God's power are being** **guarded through faith** for a salvation ready to be revealed in the last time.  In this you rejoice, though now for a little while, if necessary, you have been **grieved by various trials,  so that the tested genuineness of your faith—more precious than gold that perishes though it is tested by fire—may be found to result in praise and glory and honor** at the revelation of Jesus Christ.  Though you have not seen him, you love him. Though you do not now see him, you believe in him and rejoice with joy that is inexpressible and filled with glory,  obtaining the outcome of your faith, the salvation of your souls.

If you have not yet abandoned your own efforts to shape your own life into a life that pleases God then I encourage you to lay everything down at the foot of the cross.  Jesus Christ, the Son of God has lived THE life that pleases God and you are invited to [rest from your own efforts](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%204%3A1-13&version=ESV) and take part in His life:

> because if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved.  For with the heart one believes and is justified, and with the mouth one confesses and is saved. - Romans 10:9-10

If you are already born again by the grace of God through faith in Jesus, having appealed to God in Christ, trust that God's promise in Christ is to send His Holy Spirit to be in you to guide you into all truth, to testify to you of Jesus (reminding you of everything he said) and to [undertake the process of sanctification](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thess%204%3A1-12&version=ESV) (which is part of God's will for you).  This sanctification process often takes place in the fires of trial where we learn to subordinate our desires to the desires of God and it is ultimately for our eternal good.

> I appeal to you therefore, brothers, by the mercies of God, to present your bodies as a living sacrifice, holy and acceptable to God, which is your spiritual worship. Do not be conformed to this world, but be transformed by the renewal of your mind, that by testing you may discern what is the will of God, what is good and acceptable and perfect. - Romans 12:1-2

I do not know if God's will for you is to publish fantasy novels or do any other particular thing and you may not currently know either.  Remember that Abraham was called to go to a land that God **would show him**.  Abraham was the father of Faith precisely because God did not show him first but, rather, called him to walk by faith rather than by sight.  Abraham did and was called God's friend.

This is most often very difficult...no one enjoys discipline at the time (I know that I never have).  God is working to shape us into that which we cannot imagine but that He can clearly see.  Relax into the Potter's hands, struggle to give thanks in all circumstances, and trust in the Name of the Lord Jesus Christ.  He will never leave you nor forsake you.

Comment: Hi Mike. it's our specific policy not to answer questions like this, because we never know enough to give a good answer and we do not want to encourage people to take spiritual advice from random strangers.

Comment: @DJClayworth I tried to avoid anything that smacked of personal counsel but I understand.

Answer (score -1):

Psalms 37:4-5 "Delight thyself also in the Lord; and he shall give thee the desires of thine heart. 5 Commit thy way unto the Lord; trust also in him; and he shall bring it to pass."

I have found doing the few things that God wants us to do is His will. Study the scriptures to gain insight into who God is. 2 Timothy 2:15. Pray for His will to be done and desire to do it. Last, and most important, is to share the gospel with whoever you can. Matthew 28:19-20. Once you commit yourself to these things He will give you what He wants you to desire. We often think God will give us what our own will wants. Rather God will give us His will. If you commit yourself to this then eventually it will come to pass.

If God wants you to be a successful writer then it will happen, He doesn't have that in mind for you are you willing to do something else? Maybe you cannot make a living off your writing but you can be a blessing to someone with that talent.

Comment: Hi Husbandman. it's our specific policy not to answer questions like this, because we never know enough to give a good answer and we do not want to encourage people to take spiritual advice from random strangers.